# Python, oracle. Выдача запроса в Telegram bot

Tags: python, telebot, cx-oracle

Доброй ночи всем! Прошу помощи кто чем сможет помочь, написал бот но не могу при этом получить запрос по идентификатору.

```
    import telebot
from telebot import types
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Visual Studio\instantclient_21_3")
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
conn=cx_Oracle.connect(********)
sql = conn.cursor()
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=6)
    rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton('Код товара'), types.KeyboardButton('Наименование товара'))
    
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выбирете желаемое", reply_markup=rmk)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_unswer)


def user_unswer(message):
    if message.text == "Код товара":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Впишите код товара")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_reg)
    elif message.text == "Наименование товара":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На данный момент этот пункт не работает!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Еще раз повторяю не работает!")
def user_reg(message):
    if message.text == "":
        res=sql.execute("SELECT skucode, name from sku where skucode = '{message.text}'")
    res=sql.fetchall()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, res)
conn.close()
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Основная проблема идет в последнем `def` выдает ошибку то нет подключения, если убрать `res=sql.fetchall()` и в `bot.send_message` прописать `(message.chat.id, skucode, name)` ругается что нет таких ячеек, уже незнаю что делать подскажите кто чем может если не спите, борюсь уже 5 часов и не получается ничего хочу спать, если что пишите в коменты свои варианты завтра проснусь посмотрю отвечу

Comment: т.е. фактически когда я отправляю последний текст который есть в БД он мне не хочет выдавать, а я очень сильно хочу получить данные)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ну во-первых**, вы тут же закрываете подключение к БД в предпоследней строчке, отсюда и ошибка подключения.

**Во-вторых**, вначале функции `user_reg` вы сначала проверяете поле `text` на пустое значение, и только если оно пустое вы формируете и выполняете запрос, а запрашиваете результат в любом случае, даже если поле не пустое и запрос не был сформирован.

**В третьих**, поле text не может быть пустым, так что эта проверка никогда не сработает и вы никогда не будете формировать и выполнять запрос.

**И последнее**, *научитесь выравнивать и форматировать код.*

---

```
def user_reg(message):
    res=sql.execute("SELECT skucode, name from sku where skucode = '{message.text}'")
    res=sql.fetchall()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, res)
    

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
conn.close()
```

Comment: К сожалению пока проверить не могу сервак пал сегодня утром, чуть позже отпишусь

Comment: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty - было отправлено сообщение "210w002" без ковычек
сейчас буду мониторить что не так, но если что жду коментов,

Comment: 'res=sql.execute(f"SELECT skucode, name from sku where skucode = '{message.text}'")' добавил форматирование, бот вернул ответное сообщение 210w002 вместо того чтобы вернуть значение 210w002 и name

Comment: Еще поигрался добавил форматирование в 'bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{res}')' - выдало полноценное сообщение с кодом товара и наименованием, но теперь хочется чтобы сообщение вместо 'res' - было в виде ' "Код товара: "+f'{skucode}' + " Наименование товара: " + f'(name}'' но при этом чтобы код товара и наименование товара было в разных строчках, если есть варианты прошу накинуть, а так ищу инфу

Comment: Для доступа к полям запроса используется ассоциативный массив: `res['skucode']`